# solr dynamicField with spring data

Tags: java, solr, spring-data-solr

i have a solr core with schema like

```
<schema name="product" version="1.5">
  <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
  ...
```

my products are like

```
{name : "product1", color : "red", foo   : "bar", ....}
```

which are suppose to save on solr as

```
{name : "product1", color_t:"red", foo_t : "bar" , ....}
```

i am using spring-data-solr to connect and use solr. dynamic fields are dynamic so i can not define them in my `@SolrDocument`, hence no easy update or query on my products.

it can be done with `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer` and manually doing the job. is there anyway to use spring data to handle dynamic fields? maybe by defining a `Map` in Document and ask Spring to use map keys as solr fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `Map` defined for dynamic field as below

```
private @Field("*_t") Map<String, List<String>> textMap;
```

Assuming the _t fields are multivalued, you can have `Map<String,List>`, or just `Map<String,String>`

Comment: thanks. that was exactly what i need. how did i missed it. for does who want to know more about it [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.mapping.mappingSolr) from spring docs says what u need with examples